# CreateElement and then write innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I have been searching for the answer for 2 days now. How would someone create an element and then write it in HTML with innerHTML?

```js
function dataPull() {
      // Connects to my server from which it pulls JSON data containing start,end,summary,organizer of the event.
      fetch("http://localhost:8000/events").then((resp) => resp.json()).then(render)
    };

    function eventFilter(event) {
      eventTime = new Date(event);
      eventHours = eventTime.getHours();
      eventMinutes = eventTime.getMinutes();
      if (eventMinutes < 10) {
        eventMinutes = "0" + eventMinutes
      }
      return event = eventHours + ":" + eventMinutes;
    };

    function eventMap(eventBooked) {
      return `
        <div class="event">
            <div class="eventTime">${eventFilter(eventBooked.start)}
                <p class="timep">${eventFilter(eventBooked.end)}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="eventInfo">
                <h1 class="eventSummary"> ${eventBooked.summary}</h1>
                <p class="eventOrganizer">${eventBooked.organizer}</p>
            </div>
        </div>`;
    };

    function render(data) {
      data.events.sort(function(a, b) {
        return new Date(a.start).getTime() - new Date(b.start).getTime();
      });

      // Delete outdated events.
      let eventsNotOutdated = data.events.filter((item) => {
        let endTime = new Date(item.end);
        if (Date.now() < endTime) {
          return item;
        }
      });

      // Create a new variable for event currently in progress.
      let eventInProgress = eventsNotOutdated.filter((item) => {
        let startTime = new Date(item.start);
        if (Date.now() > startTime) {
          return item;
        }
      });

      // Same as eventsNotOutdated but without the event in progress.
      let filteredEventsNotOutdated = eventsNotOutdated.filter((item) => {
        let startTime = new Date(item.start);
        if (Date.now() < startTime) {
          return item;
        }
      });

      if (eventInProgress.length > 0 && filteredEventsNotOutdated.length >= 1) {
        return document.getElementById("eventList").innerHTML =
          `<div>
            <h1 class="announcerBig">In progress</h1>
            <div class="eventBig">
              <div class="eventTimeBig">${eventFilter(eventInProgress[0].start)}
              <p class=timep>${eventFilter(eventInProgress[0].end)}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="eventInfoBig">
              <h1 class="eventSummaryBig">${eventInProgress[0].summary}</h1>
              <p class="eventOrganizerBig">${eventInProgress[0].organizer}</p>
            </div>
           </div>
            </div>
            <div class=eventsInProgress>
            <h1 class="announcer">Later</h1>${filteredEventsNotOutdated.map(eventMap).join("")}
            </div>`;
      } else if (eventInProgress.length > 0 && filteredEventsNotOutdated.length < 1) {
        return doc.getElementById("eventList").innerHTML =
          `<div>
            <h1 class="announcerBig">In progress</h1>
            <div class="eventBig">
              <div class="eventTimeBig">${eventFilter(eventInProgress[0].start)}
                <p class=timep>${eventFilter(eventInProgress[0].end)}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="eventInfoBig">
                <h1 class="eventSummaryBig">${eventInProgress[0].summary}</h1>
                <p class="eventOrganizerBig">${eventInProgress[0].organizer}</p>
              </div>
           </div>`
      } else if (eventInProgress.length === 0 && filteredEventsNotOutdated.length > 0) {
        return document.getElementById("eventList").innerHTML =
          `<h1 class="announcerBig">Coming up next</h1>${filteredEventsNotOutdated.map(eventMap).join("")}`;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("eventList").innerHTML =
          `<p class="noevent">No meetings scheduled.</p><p class="schedule">Schedule meetings on google calendars.`;
      };
    };

    setTimeout(dataPull);
    setInterval(dataPull, 10000);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body id='body'>
  <div id='eventList' class="eventList"></div>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is a quick presentation of the code I am using. As you can see I not using any document.createElement methods, but what if instead of that backticks I would use createElement. I tried, but the problem is, that every 10 seconds (because of the interval) it calls the function and writes the same element on and on. Note: the interval is desired since the data I am pulling is constantly updating, therefore I need a constant update on my display.

Now my question: 
Is it possible to write created elements with appended children in HTML using innerHTML method?

Comment: Yes you can append children in string using innerHTML

Comment: I don't get the problem? You're already adding new elements with `.innerHTML` - which seems to work because you mentioned that it fails to work when you're not using template literals O.o

Comment: If I understand you didn't go [`node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) because it would create the same element again and again, the solution is to use [`node.removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) if you keep the child you can do `child.parentNode.removeChild(child)`

Comment: @Andreas template literals work fine, but is there a way of making this with using only the createElement. Then after creating the element write the elements innerHTML every time so it will always overwrite the previous data.

Comment: @jonatjano Yes, but I would like to make it so, that the function writes all elements I would create using createElement in the HTML and then overwrite them with new ones. Not adding them.  `node.removeChild` would work, but there is no children to remove since none of them will be created.

Comment: then you add an id to them and you do [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to get the element you need to modify and you can use `innerHTML`, `innerText` and every [other things doable on an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). Maybe I'm not fully understanding your issue :/

Comment: @jonatjano And what would I put in the element I called with id? And where would I put the element so it will not write in HTML over and over again?

Comment: @DavidB rewriting your snippets using `createElement` will take some time since it is so long :p

Comment: @DavidB does your events have an id ?

Comment: @jonatjano my events is just an array (in json) which I then call. The only id I have set is the eventList. I want to display events in eventList div using createElement instead of template literals. Calling events objects should not really be the issue, I think...

Comment: does your events have any value that make them unique ? like each event have it own title and there can not be two events with the same title at the same time or something like that

Comment: @jonatjano There is not really any filter for names, the only thing that is special is that it will sort events by time, based on their start time and date. And the function that will only display the ones which are not outdated.

Comment: @DavidB why do you show only the first event in progress ?

Comment: @jonatjano This HTML is actually a conference room display that shows which events are booked and if there is one in progress currently it will display it in a larger format. It pulls data from my server which my servers pulls data from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is your snippets using [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), it should work like your version (if on IE you'll probably need to replace `textContent` by `innerText`)

```js
function dataPull() {
  // Connects to my server from which it pulls JSON data containing start,end,summary,organizer of the event.
  fetch("http://localhost:8000/events").then((resp) => resp.json()).then(render)
};

function eventFilter(event) {
  eventTime = new Date(event);
  eventHours = eventTime.getHours();
  eventMinutes = eventTime.getMinutes();
  if (eventMinutes < 10) {
    eventMinutes = "0" + eventMinutes
  }
  return eventHours + ":" + eventMinutes;
};

function eventMap(eventBooked, classSuffix = "") {
  event = document.createElement("div")
  event.classList.add("event")

  // create time
  time = document.createElement("div")
  time.classList.add("eventTime" + classSuffix)
  time.textContent = eventFilter(eventBooked.start)
  // create timep
  timep = document.createElement("p")
  timep.classList.add("timep")
  timep.textContent = eventFilter(eventBooked.end)

  // create info
  info = document.createElement("div")
  info.classList.add(eventTime)
  // create summary
  summary = document.createElement("h1")
  summary.classList.add("eventSummary" + classSuffix)
  summary.textContent = eventBooked.summary
  // create organizer
  organizer = document.createElement("p")
  organizer.classList.add("eventOrganizer" + classSuffix)
  organizer.textContent = eventBooked.organizer

  // append everything
  event.appendChild(time)
  time.appendChild(timep)

  event.appendChild(info)
  info.appendChild(summary)
  info.appendChild(organizer)

  return event
};

function render(data) {
  data.events.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.start).getTime() - new Date(b.start).getTime();
  });

  // Delete outdated events.
  let eventsNotOutdated = data.events.filter((item) => {
    let endTime = new Date(item.end);
    if (Date.now() < endTime) {
      return item;
    }
  });

  // Create a new variable for event currently in progress.
  let eventInProgress = eventsNotOutdated.filter((item) => {
    let startTime = new Date(item.start);
    if (Date.now() > startTime) {
      return item;
    }
  });

  // Same as eventsNotOutdated but without the event in progress.
  let filteredEventsNotOutdated = eventsNotOutdated.filter((item) => {
    let startTime = new Date(item.start);
    if (Date.now() < startTime) {
      return item;
    }
  });

  let eventList = document.getElementById("eventList");
  for(let child of eventList.children) {eventList.removeChild(child)}

  if (eventInProgress.length > 0) {
    div = document.createElement("div")
    
    announcerBig = document.createElement("h1")
    announcerBig.classList.add("announcerBig")
    announcerBig.textContent = "In progress"
    
    eventBig = eventMap(eventInProgress[0], "Big")
    
    div.appendChild(announcerBig)
    div.appendChild(eventBig)
    
    eventList.appendChild(div)
    
    if (filteredEventsNotOutdated.length) {
      inProgress = document.createElement("div")
      
      announcer = document.createElement("h1")
      announcer.classList.add("announcer")
      announcer.textContent = "Later"
      
      inProgress.appendChild(announcer)
      
      filteredEventsNotOutdated.forEach(ev => {eventList.appendChild(eventMap(ev))})
      
      eventList.appendChild(inProgress)
    }
    
  } else if (eventInProgress.length === 0 && filteredEventsNotOutdated.length > 0) {
      announcerBig = document.createElement("h1")
      announcerBig.classList.add("announcerBig")
      announcerBig.textContent = "Coming up next"
      
      eventList.appendChild(announcerBig)
      
      filteredEventsNotOutdated.forEach(ev => {eventList.appendChild(eventMap(ev))})
  } else {      
      noevent = document.createElement("p")
      noevent.classList.add("noevent")
      noevent.textContent = "No meetings scheduled."
      
      schedule = document.createElement("p")
      schedule.classList.add("schedule")
      schedule.textContent = "Schedule meetings on google calendars."
      
      eventList.appendChild(noevent)
      eventList.appendChild(schedule)
  };

  return eventList
};

setTimeout(dataPull);
setInterval(dataPull, 10000);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body id='body'>
  <div id='eventList' class="eventList"></div>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

hope I didn't forget a part :p

It can be easily improved, for example :

- keep event div when event is not outdated (remove only outdated child / create only new child)
- review HTML/CSS to keep the same squeletton when there is no event in progress / no event at all

---

**EDIT** : explanation of the line

```
filteredEventsNotOutdated.forEach(ev => {eventList.appendChild(eventMap(ev))})
```

can be developed into

```
for (let ev of filteredEventsNotOutdated) {
    child = eventMap(ev)
    eventList.appendChild(child)
})
```

look at doc for [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: I really appreciate what you did. However, the code does not run as it should. It lists 3 events in progress and none in later div. But I can do that on my own. You have given me a good foundation. Not good even, perfect! Can you just explain what you did on the line where you added the for function?

Comment: @DavidB do you mean this one `filteredEventsNotOutdated.forEach(ev => {eventList.appendChild(eventMap(ev))})`?

Comment: `for(let child of eventList.children) {eventList.removeChild(child)}`
I did not really get what this for was doing so I changed it to:
`let removeChilds = function (node) {
        let last;
        while (last = node.lastChild) node.removeChild(last);
    };
    removeChilds(eventList);`

Comment: @DavidB I did not think of using while but the result is still the same every child is removed

Comment: huh... Did not work for me though. Anyways, made the code working, any tip on how to shorten the createElement class into a function, so for example `function el(tag, class) {document.createElement(tag).className(class)}`
Then I would call the function when creating an element: 
`let div = el("div","divClass")`

Comment: @DavidB you can do `function el(tag, className) {(let elem = document.createElement(tag)).classList.add(className); return elem}`. you need to use the `elem` var or you'll return the same as `classList.add` which is `undefined`
. Using `class` is not allowed as it is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords)

Comment: for my loop, it is possible I failled, didn't removed child in a while :p

Comment: Works perfectly, only thing is that I need to move `.classList` to a new line otherwise it will perform an error,.